# how to resolve "There are unresolved conflicts in the working directory" in Git desktop?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I'm new to Git and using GIT Desktop to pull and push code. I got this error while I was pulling code from the repository. I got this error how can I resolve it
[image: As shown in give screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs, there are 2 ways of [Addressing Merge Conflicts](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts).

I am not sure if they can be also implemented through GitHub Desktop.